# CUDA - multiple kernels

Tags: cuda, gpu

```
void func(){
int block_size, grid_size;

block_size = 32;
grid_size = 16;

gpu_kernel1<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(x,y);
gpu_kernel2<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(x,y);
gpu_kernel3<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(x,y);
gpu_kernel4<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(x,y);
}
```

Here is my example cuda script , in this situation ,
gpu_kernel1 , gpu_kernel2  ,gpu_kernel3 , gpu_kernel4 are executed at once?

I want to execute gpu_kernel2 after gpu_kernel1 is completely done. How can I do it?

Comment: As you didn't specify a stream, they should all run on the default stream and therefore not in parallel.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

While calls to many CUDA functions are asynchronous (i.e. the CPU code will not wait until that particular thing finishes executing to continue to the next), such as kernel calls, that does not mean that all things that have been asynchronously called will happen simultaneously (in fact, not even single kernel calls are simultaneous, they are divided in blocks etc).

What an asynchronous call is is basically an instruction to someone else to start doing something, while the process that calls the instruction does not wait for it to have been finished. In CUDA, that "someone else" is the GPU. If you don't do otherwise, the GPU will have its own "main thread", or in CUDA terms, *default stream* where things will be queued up. Instructions in this main thread will be queued one after the other sequentially.

In your case,  your CPU will queue all 4 kernels intermediately, but they won't be executed in parallel, they go to the default stream get sequentially queued and executed by the GPU, even if the CPU is not waiting for them and has move on to do other things. So to answer your question: your are already executing `gpu_kernel2` after `gpu_kernel1`.

Now, to answer the opposite question, if you wanted to execute kernels together, you would need to create your own streams for each "thread" in the GPU, and then call the kernels on those streams. This gets more complicated, as some instructions can be done like this, some dont (multiple memory copies, kernels occupying all SM, etc), but reading about streams in CUDA would be the right place to start.